# Why is this method called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I refresh page, I must click button twice in order to get prompt. After that, each time I click same button and call classicHover() method (without refreshing), i get one plus prompt(two prompts, three prompts, four...).

This is code:

```
function classicHover(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        gridSize = prompt("Set Grid Size")
        $('.container').empty();

        for(i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
            $('.container').append("<div>a</div>");
        };
    });
};
```

Button:

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Set New Grid" onclick="classicHover()" />
```

What am I doing wrong? I am JS/jQuery newbie btw

Comment: don't have a jquery click event listener inside the function, it'll have been triggered by the input. Have one or the other not both.

Comment: when you click on your button, you call `classicHover`. that function add a listener to the `#button1`  button every time it is called. you basically don't need that `$('#button1').click(function(){ ` line

Comment: You are adding the event handler every time `button1` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your click calls `classicHover`. `classicHover` adds a function to the button's listener. Each time you click it, you add something to its listener. So the first click adds 1. The second click runs the 1 and adds another. The third click runs the 2 and adds another. Repeat for each click.

Comment: What is solution, .unbind() ?

Comment: @11223342124 Don't call `.click()` inside the click handler. Just call it once in `$(document).ready()`.